# Является ли связанным сочетание?

Tags: синтаксис

*Тишину нарушает журчание весёлых ручейков*

Войдет ли "тишину" в сказуемое?

Comment: А почему вы думаете,  что сочетание "нарушает тишину" является связанным?  Эта информация нужна, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Sharon Потому что глагол "нарушать" имеет сильное управление и требует обязательного распространителя.

Answer (score 1):

Не является.

При прямом порядке слов:

*Журчание весёлых ручейков нарушает тишину.*

Основа: журчание нарушает.

"Нарушать" - самодостаточный переходный глагол.

[**синтаксический разбор предложения**](https://textovod.com/syntax)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше так: журчание (подлежащее) — **чьё?** — ручейков (определение). Ну или уж «чего?» – тогда дополнение. Но никак не часть подлежащего!

Comment: Вопрос же не о ручейках, а о тишине. Мне тоже не понравился глагол, хотелось бы видеть его в связке с тишиной, но вот, проверила. Может, сайт невнятный?

Comment: А, поняла Вас! Ручейки подчёркнуты как подлежащее! А я среагировала только на двойную черту под нарушает.

Comment: @Слава По-моему, как раз _журчание ручейков_ должно быть подлежащим. То есть как неделимое словосочетание.

Comment: Действительно, в нашем случае журчание ручейков лучше рассматривать как подлежащее.

Comment: Прямо-таки РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ в теории несвободных словосочетаний.  Всё, что определяет подлежащее, является подлежащим тоже?  Журчание ручья – синтаксически неделимое словосочетание? Но тогда главное слово (журчание) должно  быть  отвлеченным: человек, люди, мужчина, женщина, вещь, дело, занятие, вопрос, место, время и др.  А здесь это название действия.

Comment: Не было бы вопросов в таком предложении: "Пешеход нарушает правила дорожного движения". Но в данном случае, как мне кажется, ситуация другая.

Comment: Было у нас журчание ручейков.  Связанное сочетание? Конечно, это связь управление. Неделимое сочетание, один член предложения (подлежащее)? А вот сейчас проверим: журчание веселых ручейков. Разделилось!  Теперь существительное управляет словосочетанием.  Тоже единый член предложения? Тогда можно считать, что  двусоставное предложение состоит из двух неделимых сочетаний. Договорились, в общем, до абсурда.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, глагол "***нарушать***" имеет **сильное** управление и требует обязательного **распространителя**. Но при синтаксическом разборе **прямое дополнение**  выделяется отдельно, связанным такое сочетание не называют.  Его нужно отличать от **синтаксически неделимых** сочетаний.

**А какая разница?**

Вот определение:

```
Словосочетание является синтаксически неделимым, если в 
другом, синтаксически делимом словосочетании оно выполняет 
функцию главного или зависимого  компонента, а в предложении 
— функцию какого-то одного члена предложения.
```

Другими словами, сочетание считается **синтаксически неделимым,** если оно **всегда остается таким** и является **единым членом** предложения. Рассмотрим сочетание ***нарушать тишину.***

***Он нарушает  тишину.***  Это (сказуемое + дополнение) или одно сказуемое?

Возьмем другое предложение: ***Не надо нарушать тишину.***  Здесь сказуемое ***не надо нарушать,*** а ***тишину*** — дополнение.

Сочетание оказалось **синтаксически делимым.**

**Большой толковый словарь**

**НАРУШИТЬ**, -шу, -шишь; св. что. 1. **Помешать** обычному течению, ходу чего-л.; прервать. Н. сон. Н. ход мыслей. **Н. тишину,** молчание. Н. покой, уединение. Н. сообщение между городами. Н. связь. 2. **Не соблюсти, преступить.** Н. порядок. Н. дисциплину. Н. соглашение. Н. государственную границу (офиц.; незаконно перейти государственную границу). 3. **Разрушить, повредить.** Н. причёску. Н. обмен веществ. Н. кровообращение. Нарушать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Нарушаться, -ается; страд. Нарушение (см.).

Comment: Не совсем все равно понятно, например. Одержать победу - победить, нарушать тишину - шуметь. Почему нет?

Comment: Это семантика, а в грамматике свои порядки.   Там дано определение неразложимых сочетаний, это грамматический термин. Обычно синтаксически неделимые сочетания образуются на основе существительных, например: два дерева, брат с сестрой, любой из них, Или такие: что-то тяжелое, где-то в поле. Есть сложные: котенок с белыми лапками, ехать с большой скоростью. Глагольные сочетания: можно построить, родиться счастливой.  И т.д.  Отдельно изучается контекстуально неразложимые сочетания.

Comment: Тема сложная, но если есть желание разобраться в ней, нужно начать с базовых понятий, которые даны в учебниках по грамматике.  Лингвисты дают названия, у них определенная терминология, свои приемы. Пользователям языка могут в этом разобраться, но не изменить что-либо. Источник: стр. 6  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf Или еще какой учебник.

Comment: А в чем отличная грамматика? И там, и там глаголы сильного управления; и там, и там существительные являются зависимыми.

Comment: Нарушить тишину вполне может сойти за ОГИО, тем более что есть фразеологизированное "нарушить покой". Я уже видела этот учебник, но ничего нового там не почерпнула. Для меня между данными конструкциями нет принципиальной разницы. Если для вас есть, то покажите, в чем она заключается: я искренне не понимаю.

Comment: "Возьмем другое предложение: Не надо нарушать тишину. Здесь сказуемое не надо нарушать, а тишину — дополнение" этот пример я совсем не поняла. Причем тут "не надо"? Можем так же сказать: "не надо шуметь" - смысл не изменится.

Comment: Фразеологическое сочетание? Но здесь прямое значение, не фразеологическое, как мне думается. Одним словом не заменить, обычное предложение. То есть надо проводить анализ по фразеологизмам.  Поэтому я спросила вас, прежде чем начала отвечать. Но ы говорили про сильное управление.

Comment: Но и в "покой" оно прямое, но там бы было частью сказуемого. Чем вам "шуметь" не нравится в качестве замены? Про сильное управление я к слову сказала, в том плане, что требуется глаголу зависимый компонент.

Comment: Эту тему (неразложимых сочетаний) надо начинать изучать по грамматическим учебникам.  И не надо мешать ее с фразеологией.  Также это не школьная тема, как правило. Я помогла вам, чем сумела.  К тому же Вы расширяете тему вопроса.  Подождите других ответов, пожалуйста.

Comment: В ОГЭ примеры подобного толка встречаются: будит воображение, иметь память, но там тоже включают в состав сказуемого. Тоже прямых синонимов нет.

Comment: Извините еще раз, я ответила вам на ваш конкретный вопрос. Конкретика - это правило форума.

Comment: Да. Спасибо. К сожалению, я так и не поняла, почему так.

Comment: К сожалению, я не сумела вам объяснить.  Хорошо хоть, себе кое-что объяснила)  Я имею ввиду отличие прямых дополнений от неразложимых словосочетаний.